# Would language extensions/spin-offs be ontopic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Might be too close to [this](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-questions-about-specific-languages-on-topic) question, but would questions relating to expanding or basing oneself on existing languages be on-topic on this site?

Take for example the recent explosion of C++ successors (Circle, Carbon, Cpp2), would a question like 'What C++ compilers are simple to modify syntax on?' or 'What are some syntax options for simpler generic functions' (like Cpp2's `arg: _`) be on-topic?

Answer (score 3):

> What C++ compilers are simple to modify syntax on?

This would be closed, because it [asks to find or recommend off-site resources](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/89). A question more like "how can syntax extensions of C++ be implemented?" could be on-topic.

> What are some syntax options for simpler generic functions

Questions about syntax options are generally on-topic, but this one seems like it would be a duplicate of [this existing question](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/122/89).